# Find Elasticsearch value of empty object

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to run a query to see how many documents have an empty object stored as their value.  For example it would return a document like:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_source": {
      "otherfield": "abc",
      "somefield": {}
    }
  }
]
```

But not either no field / the field with an undefined value, or the field with an object containing attributes:

```
"hits": [
  {
    "_source": {
      "otherfield": "abc",
      // <-- note no "somefield"
    }
  },
  {
    "_source": {
      "otherfield": "abc",
      "somefield": { "field1": "value1" }
    }
  }
]
```

But the query I have will also return documents where the field is an object with attributes such as `"somefield": { "field1": "value1" }`

```
GET /documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "somefield.field1"
          }
        },
      ]
      "should": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "somefield"
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Using Elasticsearch 5.4

Answer (score 1):

The following query should be enough to find all documents with empty `somefield` field:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "exists": {
          "field": "somefield"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

While your query is a bit confusing for me. First you are trying to find any documents where `somefield.field1` does not exist. Then you combine content of `must_not` clause with mutually exclusive content of `should` clause that filters documents with non-empty `somefield`. Actually `should` clause is translated into

```
"should": [{
    "exists": {"field": "somefield.field1"}
}]
```

So your query should not match neither documents with `somefield: {}` nor documents with `somefield: {field1: value1}`.

Comment: Thanks. Have clarified question to make it clear I want to find all documents where the object is empty as opposed to the field not being present at all or the field value being an object with attributes.

Comment: @AJP Thank you for clarification. Now I understand your question. I think it is not possible to distinguish document with empty `somefield` from document without `somefield` at all. From the point of Elasticsearch they are the same. You can verify it by using _Term Vectors_ query (`GET /my_index/my_type/<id>/_termvectors?fields=*`). Such differentiation should be done on the client side.

Comment: Interesting, thanks.  Hadn't come across `Term Vectors` before.  It's surprising that there's no query like `match: { somefield: "{}" }` as opposed to `match: { somefield: undefined }` (you'd actually use the `must_not: { exists: { field: "somefield" }}`) as the values of the field in the documents are clearly different from each other.